# Find Next and Previous Timestamps Within Ruby Array of Timestamps for a Given Timestamp

Tags: ruby, timestamp

So if I have an array of timestamps like so (many more than this in reality):

```
2013-07-27 18:02:59.865572
2013-07-27 18:29:00.132601
2013-07-27 19:00:00.081585
2013-07-27 19:29:00.273857
2013-07-27 20:00:00.011761
```

And I wanted to find which two timestamps **2013-07-27 19:13:00.081585** falls between, what would be the most elegant way with Ruby?

I can envision an ugly bunch of loops and if statements to do this, but being a novice Ruby programmer I suspect there is a much more elegant way to do this (that I absolutely cannot find!).

Thanks!

Comment: if the array is sorted, a binary search sound like the way to go

Comment: It can be, but I am just confused as to the logic of comparing timestamps with Ruby to find the inner and outer matches from the list. Performance is less of a concern for me.

Comment: I think `Enumerable#each_cons` will work here pretty well.  I just don't know how exact you want the difference in times to be.

Comment: Do you want the new timestamp to be in that array later?

Comment: @squiguy so you're saying for each_cons my block should check if the desired timestamp is next to the last timestamp passed into the block?

Comment: I thought you meant in between the two times.

Comment: @tessi I just need the timestamp before and after the timestamp I have (from the example 2013-07-27 19:13:00.081585)

Comment: Is the timestamp you have always going to be in the array?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a few things.

- Whether the timestamp you're looking for is known to be in the array.
- What *between* means.
- Whether elements in the array are unique.

Let's assume the array is sorted, or that you'll sort it yourself beforehand.

If `your_timestamp` is known to be in the array, you can find its index with `timestamp_array.index(your_timestamp)`. Logically, the elements your_timestamp is between will have indexes immediately above and below. There are two things to watch for.

1. Falling off either end of the array.
2. Duplicate timestamps.

If `your_timestamp` is either the first or last element in the array, you won't have an element with an index immediately below the first or immediately above the last.

If your array contains duplicate timestamps, you're liable to return `your_timestamp` as one of the values. It seems like you *don't* want to do that, but there isn't strictly a right or wrong answer here. It's application-dependent.

If you don't know whether `your_timestamp` is in the array, or if you *don't* want `your_timestamp` as one of the values (unless it's the first or last element of the sorted array, that is), then this might be a better approach.

```
timestamp_array.sort.each_cons(2){ |ts| 
  # If your desired timestamp is in the timestamp array, you'll
  # get at least two pairs of timestamps.
  answer.concat ts if your_desired_timestamp.between?(ts[0], ts[1])
}
# If you have more than 2 elements, return only the first and last element.
if answer.length > 2
  answer = answer.first, answer.last
end
p answer

["2013-07-27 18:29:00.132601", "2013-07-27 19:29:00.273857"]
```

This works correctly for duplicate timestamps, and there's no danger of falling off either end of the array.

Some optimizations are available. For example, you can switch to a binary search (bsearch method), which might be worthwhile if you have very large arrays; you can eliminate the conditional `if answer.length > 2`; etc.

Answer (score 0):

So someone else left an answer and then redacted it for some reason, I think it was because there was an error, but it led me in the right direction, as did @squiguy.

```
timestamp_array.sort.each_cons(2).select{ |a,b|  
  puts a
    if a < your_desired_timestamp and b > your_desired_timestamp)
      puts 'this is the valid range for ' + your_desired_timestamp.to_s
    end
  puts b
}
```

Thanks Guys and Gals!

Comment: You can give your answer the checkmark, to show others who find your question which answer was the best one.